# What is the requiment for King of San Andreas title in GTA Sa?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

According to this page: [Criminal Ratings in GTA San Andreas](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Criminal_Ratings_in_GTA_San_Andreas)

> Godfather     500,000-999,999
>
> King of San Andreas   1,000,000+

My Criminal Ratings is now greater than 1,000,000 but I'm still stuck at Godfather. I think there is other requirement to reach King of San Andreas. So what is the requiment for King of San Andreas title in GTA Sa?

---

You can test this by doing the following:

Step 1: Start new game

Step 2: Change the stats: "Total legitimate kills" to 2,000,000 with Cheat Engine:

The memory address of "Total legitimate kills" is `gta_sa.exe+7790E4`

Data type of "Total legitimate kills" is `4 Bytes`.

Step 3: Back to the game and you can see your Criminal Ratings is 2,000,000 but your title is only Godfather, not King of San Andreas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out, what I missed is money. The full requirement for King of SanAndreas title is:

- Criminal Ratings is 1,000,000+
- Money is 10,000,001+

---

You can test this by doing the following:

Step 1: Start new game

Step 2: Change the stats: "Total legitimate kills" to 1,000,000 with Cheat Engine:

The memory address of "Total legitimate kills" is `gta_sa.exe+7790E4`

Data type of "Total legitimate kills" is `4 Bytes`.

Step 3: Change your money to 10,000,001 with Cheat Engine:

The memory address of "Money" is `gta_sa.exe+77CE50`

Data type of "Money" is `4 Bytes`.

Step 4: Back to your game and wait a few second for your money to update to 10,000,001. Then you'll see you've earned the title: King of San Andeas.